# SQL - Convert results of SELECT statement to a parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

consider the following stored procedure :

```
alter procedure getRisks @id int, @convertedRiskValue int
as
select top 1 table1.id, idRisk, riskValue from table1
left join table2
on table1.id = table2.id
where table1.id= @id
order by table2.id desc
```

- The `idRisk` value will always vary from 1-4 and the `riskValue` will vary from 0-1000 .
- What i want to do ?

  - I want to convert the `riskValue` to `idRisk` "type" as follows :

[image]

, then put it into `@convertedRiskValue` and return it from the select statement.

Any ideas ?

Comment: `CASE WHEN RiskValue >= 0 AND RiskValue <= 250 THEN 1 WHEN RiskValue >= 251...` etcetera. (And you can't put anything in `@convertedRiskValue` to return to the caller unless you make the parameter `OUTPUT`.)

Comment: Left Join? What if you dont have value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
alter procedure getRisks @id int, @convertedRiskValue int
as
select top 1 table1.id, CASE WHEN RiskValue >= 0 AND RiskValue <= 250 THEN 1 
WHEN RiskValue >= 251 and RiskValue <= 500 THEN 2
WHEN RiskValue >= 501 and RiskValue <= 750 THEN 3
WHEN RiskValue >= 751 and RiskValue <= 1000 THEN 4 end as idRiskType
 , riskValue from table1
left join table2
on table1.id = table2.id
where table1.id= @id
order by table2.id desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   riskValue,
   CASE 
     WHEN riskValue > -1 AND riskValue < 251 THEN 1
     WHEN riskValue > 250 AND riskValue < 501 THEN 2
     WHEN riskValue > 500 AND riskValue < 751 THEN 3
     WHEN riskValue > 750 AND riskValue < 1001 THEN 4
  END AS idRisk
FROM Table
```